# SMS feature in C++ for Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c++, dll, sms, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to create a wrapper DLL in C++ for Windows Mobile 6.5. This wrapper DLL should provide all the SMS feature available, and it will be used in C# apps.

I did some search and found that there are 2 separate DLL for SMS: `SMS.lib` or `CEMAPI.dll`. I'm confused on which one of them should i be using.

Reading some articles reveal that `SMS.lib` is newer but lacks the feature to check the incoming SMS, while `CEPMAPI.dll` is older and need to register key in registry to use, but will support features such as intercepting new message and etc.

With this said, i'm a bit incline in using `SMS.lib` as it's easier to implement, but i would like to know which is the right one to use? Is there any de facto lib that winmo developers goes to when implementing SMS feature?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, why are you using a wrapper in C++ and don't use existing C# methods for this feature?

Comment: There are some features that are only available to `C++`, such as the ability to read through the messages in inbox and their status. I'm using a library called `MAPIdotnet` now and it seems to be working. Just the documentation for Windows Mobile is really getting me dizzy...

Comment: Ok I understand. I used PocketOutlook API in C# but it's not offering all the functionalitites without wrapping